# How to find monitor model and related information in linux?

Tags: command-line, hardware, monitors

I want to correct my color profile, so I need to find my monitor model so that I can download the correct ICC (or ICM) file. Is there a way to find out the monitor model in Linux?

Comment: You mean apart from just looking at the back of the monitor where all this is listed? Does it _have_ to be a software solution?

Comment: You could always run `grep -i 'Monitor name' /var/log/Xorg.0.log` and see what it returns. It give me both the make & model number.

Comment: I don't think there's any sure way, @Bib. I get no output for your command, for example (`grep -i 'Monitor name' /var/log/Xorg.*.log` in my case). I also tried some of the options given [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/371261/85695) and didn't get anything useful on my system. Maybe the `read-edid` command would work, but  wouldn't expect all monitors to make this information available since monitors are almost always easily accessible, sitting on a desk, and you can just look behind them.

Comment: @terdon Software that wants to know the characteristics of the monitor, such as a display server wanting to know the monitor's possible and preferred resolutions, or software that wants to select a color profile, needs to know the monitor characteristics. AFAIK all modern monitors (not ancient CRT's) support EDID (which doesn't necessarily mean they fill all the fields correctly).

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' yes, but would they ever need the monitor's manufacturer or the specific model? What they need is the characteristics, as you said, and those are also exposed by `xrandr` and various other tools, but I doubt there will be a sure-fire way of getting the name of the manufacturer or the model. I may well be wrong, of course.

Comment: @terdon The manufacturer and model name are part of the standard EDID information. You'd need that, for example, for a color profile (to know exactly what color a given RGB value appears at — R=42 on one monitor may not be as bright as R=42 on another monitor).

Comment: OK, I'm sure you're right @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil', but on my Arch running on a P14s Thinkpad, with 2 HP external monitors connected, `get-edid| parse-edit` and even `parse-edid < /sys/class/drm/card0-DP-3/edid` fail, and the xrandr output or the various logs I checked don't contain the monitor names. If you have a sure way of getting this, I'd love to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Short of reading the information off your monitor itself (most have their vendor and model listed on them, or available in their on-screen menus), you can read the screen descriptors using [`read-edid`](http://www.polypux.org/projects/read-edid/):

```
sudo get-edid | parse-edid
```

This will output an X.org configuration section for your monitor, including its vendor and model name.

Comment: his is read-edid version 3.0.2. Prepare for some fun.
Attempting to use i2c interface
No EDID on bus 0
No EDID on bus 1
No EDID on bus 2
No EDID on bus 3
No EDID on bus 4
No EDID on bus 5
No EDID on bus 6
No EDID on bus 7
Looks like no busses have an EDID. Sorry!

Comment: @kensai you might want to ask a new question.